# 'Git clone' displays a 'RPC failed' error

Tags: git, rpc, git-clone

I'm encountering an issue while trying to clone the TensorFlow models repository using the command:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models
```

The error message I receive is:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
```

I've tried changing my internet connection, but the problem persists. Additionally, I attempted adjusting the `http.postBuffer` size with:

```bash
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

However, this did not resolve the issue.

Any insights or solutions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) explains why `http.postBuffer` doesn't have any effect for clones.  In addition, you're using HTTP/2, so it can't possibly have any meaningful effect for that reason, either.  All it does is waste memory, so you'll probably want to remove that configuration.